# multiple if statements output with namedtuple

Tags: python, namedtuple

I am trying to arrange the if statements but still there is an error that makes my code doesn't continue the loop. Can anyone help to rearrange the logic of if statements. Thank you in advance

```py
import re
from collections import namedtuple

MyMenu = namedtuple('MyMenu', ['index','dish','price'])

_menu = []
_menu.append(MyMenu(1, 'Plate A', '($30.50)'))
_menu.append(MyMenu(2, 'Plate B', '($26.50)'))
_menu.append(MyMenu(3, 'Plate C', '($30.50)'))
_menu.append(MyMenu(4, 'Plate D', '($35.50)'))
_menu.append(MyMenu(5, 'Plate E', '($32.50)'))
_menu.append(MyMenu(6, 'Plate F', '($29.50)'))
_menu.append(MyMenu(7, 'Plate G', '($30.50)'))
_menu.append(MyMenu(8, 'Plate H', '($21.50)'))
total_bill = 0.0
order_summary = []
print("Welcome to Our Restaurant!\n")
print("Here is our meue:")
for entry in _menu:
    index = str(getattr(entry,'index')).ljust(8)
    descr = getattr(entry,'dish').ljust(25)
    price = getattr(entry,'price').ljust(7)
    print ('{0}{1}{2}'.format(index,descr,price))
print("\nWhat would you like to order?")
while True:
    order = input('')
    if 9 > int(order) > 0:
        item = _menu.__getitem__(int(order)). dish
        price = _menu.__getitem__(int(order)).price
        a= float("".join(re.findall("\d+\.\d+", _menu.__getitem__(int(order)).price)))
        print("You've selected {}! That would be ${:.2f}".format(item, a))
        total_bill += a
        order_summary.append(item)
        print("Would you like to add more items? (y/n)")
        #continue
        if order == "n":
            print("###################################################")
            print("Your order summary: {", ', '.join(order_summary), '}')
            print("Total Price: $", total_bill)
            break
        elif order == "y":
            item = _menu.__getitem__(int(order)).dish
            price = _menu.__getitem__(int(order)).price
            a = float("".join(re.findall("\d+\.\d+", _menu.__getitem__(int(order)).price)))
            print("You've selected {}! That would be ${:.2f}".format(item, a))
            total_bill += a
            order_summary.append(item)
            continue
   else:
       print("Selection Not Found!")
       print("Would you like to add more items? (y/n)")
       if order == "n":
           print("No items ordered at Carmine's :(")
           break
       elif order == "y":
           item = _menu.__getitem__(int(order)).dish
           price = _menu.__getitem__(int(order)).price
           a = float("".join(re.findall("\d+\.\d+", _menu.__getitem__(int(order)).price)))
           print("You've selected {}! That would be ${:.2f}".format(item, a))
           total_bill += a
           order_summary.append(item)
           continue
```

Comment: please use the code formatting , so your code is more readable

Comment: *"There is an error that makes my code doesn't continue the loop"* What error? Show us the error message, with the line number and full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

You were close. It now loops, but you need to fix your index. List index starts with 0, not 1. So if I select 1, I get plate B, not plate A.

```
import re
from collections import namedtuple

MyMenu = namedtuple('MyMenu', ['index','dish','price'])

_menu = []
_menu.append(MyMenu(1, 'Plate A', '($30.50)'))
_menu.append(MyMenu(2, 'Plate B', '($26.50)'))
_menu.append(MyMenu(3, 'Plate C', '($30.50)'))
_menu.append(MyMenu(4, 'Plate D', '($35.50)'))
_menu.append(MyMenu(5, 'Plate E', '($32.50)'))
_menu.append(MyMenu(6, 'Plate F', '($29.50)'))
_menu.append(MyMenu(7, 'Plate G', '($30.50)'))
_menu.append(MyMenu(8, 'Plate H', '($21.50)'))
total_bill = 0.0
order_summary = []
print("Welcome to Our Restaurant!\n")
print("Here is our meue:")
for entry in _menu:
    index = str(getattr(entry,'index')).ljust(8)
    descr = getattr(entry,'dish').ljust(25)
    price = getattr(entry,'price').ljust(7)
    print ('{0}{1}{2}'.format(index,descr,price))
while True:
    order = input("\nWhat would you like to order?")
    if 9 > int(order) > 0:
        item = _menu.__getitem__(int(order)).dish
        price = _menu.__getitem__(int(order)).price
        a = float("".join(re.findall("\d+\.\d+", _menu.__getitem__(int(order)).price)))
        print("You've selected {}! That would be ${:.2f}".format(item, a))
        total_bill += a
        order_summary.append(item)
        userAnswer = input("Would you like to add more items? (y/n)")
        if "n" in userAnswer:
            print("###################################################")
            print("Your order summary: {", ', '.join(order_summary), '}')
            print("Total Price: $", total_bill)
            break
        elif "y" in userAnswer:
            item = _menu.__getitem__(int(order)).dish
            price = _menu.__getitem__(int(order)).price
            a = float("".join(re.findall("\d+\.\d+", _menu.__getitem__(int(order)).price)))
            print("You've selected {}! That would be ${:.2f}".format(item, a))
            total_bill += a
            order_summary.append(item)
            continue
    else:
       print("Selection Not Found!")
       print("Would you like to add more items? (y/n)")
       if order == "n":
           print("No items ordered at Carmine's :(")
           break
       elif order == "y":
           item = _menu.__getitem__(int(order)).dish
           price = _menu.__getitem__(int(order)).price
           a = float("".join(re.findall("\d+\.\d+", _menu.__getitem__(int(order)).price)))
           print("You've selected {}! That would be ${:.2f}".format(item, a))
           total_bill += a
           order_summary.append(item)
           continue
```